# Is it possible to parameterize log4j version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, log4j

We have few hundreds of microservices which use log4j.

We need to upgrade log4j version for the 3rd time in a week due to vulnerabilities.

Is there a way to parameterize log4j version being used (and maybe store the version as a parameter on AWs Parameter Store?)

This way i can just change version in one place and the new version would apply to all microservices while rebuilding them?

Comment: There probably is, but without any details about how you are building all those micro services (any sort of CI/CD technology?) , and what dependency management tool you are using (maven, gradle, etc.) there's no way to provide an actual answer to your question.

Comment: We're using lombok maven

Comment: Lombok is not build tool, it is a library, just like log4j. Yes, you are using maven, but how does your build pipeline looks like? Are you using Jenkins or AWS CodeBuild/CodeDeploy? Or maybe something else? How does your build pipeline connect to AWS?

Answer (score 0):

This is *possible* but not *practical*.

Java is designed to load code at runtime. If you implement your own ClassLoader, you can retrieve class definitions from anywhere, including over the network.

However, there's no easy way to integrate your own classloader into whatever deployment framework you might be using (unless you're running Java from the command-line with your own `main()`). And logging has to be configured early, certainly before the AWS SDK (which depends on having a logging framework to log its actions). So you would also have to write your own class server in order to specify the library version in Parameter Store.

An alternative solution is to define your dependencies as "provided," meaning that they won't be packaged with the JAR or WAR by your build process:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then, you need to install the "blessed" versions of those dependencies on the deployment platform.

For Lambda, this is easy: create a [layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html). To push out a new dependency, you'd create a new version of the layer and update all of your functions to use it.

If you're using EC2, then you'd "pre-bake" an AMI with all the "standard" dependencies. For ECS or EKS, you'd create a base image with the dependencies. How you actually use those dependencies depends on how you do deployments, but most frameworks let you specify a directory that's added to the classpath.

While this can take some of the pain out of deploying a hotfix, it can introduce new pain. If all of your services have the same base dependencies, then you have to verify that upgrading dependencies won't break backwards compatibility. And to gain new functionality, you'll have to upgrade all of your services at once.